# Selenium automated test using List of links and set of commands foreach item in list

Tags: c#, selenium

With Selenium Automated Testing, how do you collect a list of links and perform the same commands foreach item in that list?

```
        IList<IWebElement> reviewLinks = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("a"));

        //I would like to perform the following for each Review item// in the //list
        reviewLinks.First(Review => Review.Text == "Review").Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctlSeverity")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@value='75']")).Click();
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#rblSelectedAction_0")).Click();
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("TextBox1")).SendKeys("AutoTest");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctlActionPlan")).SendKeys("AutoTest");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctlManagementResponse")).SendKeys("AutoTest");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("LinkButton1")).Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a simple foreach loop.

```
foreach(var link in reviewLinks)
{
    if(link.Text.Equals("Review"))
    {
        link.Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctlSeverity")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@value='75']")).Click();
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#rblSelectedAction_0")).Click();
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("TextBox1")).SendKeys("AutoTest");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctlActionPlan")).SendKeys("AutoTest");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctlManagementResponse")).SendKeys("AutoTest");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("LinkButton1")).Click();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.  I tried that and it completes the actions for the first link and then does not go onto the next.  I even entered an implicit wait after the last command on second try.

Comment: Does it matter that it is doing a postback upon clicking link and LinkButton1?

Comment: There are ten reviewLinks per page

Comment: At what point in your code is the page preforming a post back?

Comment: <a id="LinkButton1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctPrivateInfoLinkButton1','')">Update</a>

Comment: If you debug your code, `reviewLinks` contains the count of 10 `IWebElements`?

Comment: It seems to have found all 56 links. Not sure if this is important but If a user attempts to access the next page of links before the first 10 have been reviewed, they will get an error.

Comment: One sec, there are actually only 45 that it should find.  I am going to try to be more specific and then try again.  However, it will still need to page through to access the other links.

Comment: I changed it to say  IList<IWebElement> reviewLinks = driver.FindElements(By.Id("LinkButton3")); 
so now it only finds the 10 links but it still finishes the first item and fails on second cycle with staleelementreference.  Are we supposed to move this conversation to chat?